Unable to Copy Syntax Color from VS2019 to MS Word, Change 'Max Length'
This one had me going really bad and I didn't find mention of this solution anywhere else.
I have a rather large program I was trying to copy into Word.
All options were verified correct in both programs.
Then I stumbled on the fact that if I copied a small section of code it included syntax coloring.
There is a box labeled 'Max Length' under the checkbox for 'Copy rich text on copy/cut'.
The default is 30,000. I went to 100,000 before I could fully copy the entire code in one shot.
If I only noticed 10240000 in this post, or if the poster had spoken to it, It's probably there I just didn't see.
Copy the code text from MS Visual Studio and keeping the source color and formatting
In VS2019 there is a checkbox 'Use accurate classification' Does anyone know what this actually does?
